# Setting up dpkg Multiarch on Ubuntu 22.04, libc dependency error

Tags: glibc, cross-compilation

I want to do cross-compilation for my Beaglebone Black and use packages managed by APT.

I've already installed the crossbuild-essential-armhf package, so I do have a toolchain that is able to build for the Beagle platform, but I'm simply having trouble using other libraries like you regularly would through apt on your host machine.

The possibility definitely exists that I've misunderstood something about dpkg and apt..

Anyways.

I've tried: https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO with varying degrees of success. What I've done so far:

1. Having added the armhf architecture to dpkg and done apt update, APT had the following issue:

> E: Failed to fetch http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.225.254.116 80]
> E: Failed to fetch http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.225.254.116 80]
> E: Failed to fetch http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 130.225.254.116 80]
> E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]

From what I've understood, the armhf packages are at ports.ubuntu.com, so I've added

> deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy main universe multiverse

To my apt sources.list. This seems to have helped, APT is now at least able to find packages such as libsqlite3-dev:armhf

2. Trying to install libsqlite3-dev:armhf I'm met with the following from apt:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> libsqlite3-dev:armhf : Depends: libsqlite3-0:armhf (= 3.37.2-2) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: libc6-dev:armhf but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I then tried to install libc6-dev:armhf which yields:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> libc-dev-bin:armhf : Depends: libc6:armhf (> 2.35) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: libc6:armhf (< 2.36) but it is not going to be installed
> libc6-dev:armhf : Depends: libc6:armhf (= 2.35-0ubuntu3) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: linux-libc-dev:armhf but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: libtirpc-dev:armhf but it is not going to be installed
> libcrypt1:armhf : Depends: libc6:armhf (>= 2.25) but it is not going to be installed
> libnsl-dev:armhf : Depends: libtirpc-dev:armhf but it is not going to be installed
> libnsl2:armhf : Depends: libc6:armhf (>= 2.33) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: libtirpc3:armhf (>= 1.0.2) but it is not going to be installed

libc6:armhf is at version 2.35 in the main repository: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/armhf/libc6-dev

So I don't really see how the dependency can be met? Or why it isn't.

Seems Libc6:armhf, linux-libc-dev:armhf, libtirpc-dev:armhf, and libtirpc3:armhf packages are either not available in the repositories or there are conflicts between different versions of these packages. Which I find weird, so I think I've messed something up or am missing something..

As a sidenote The crossbuild-essential package installed libc6-dev-armhf-cross, so I do infact have the library installed...

I'm on a Ubuntu 22.04 x86_64 machine.